# Javascript settimeout

Tags: javascript

I want my users to see one confirm box after say 15 min,alerting them about the session timeout.I want this process to continue repeatedly.
That is even if the user selects cancel from the confirm box he will get the same alert after 15 min.

Comment: Yep, just click the little check mark next to the best answer. It makes folks want to answer you more.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function if you want it to run repeatedly:

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert('hello world');
}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

Also you might take a look at the [jquery idleTimer](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) plugin which allows you to detect periods of user inactivity and take some actions.

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(alert(Session Timeout),90000);
```

for *confirm box*

```
setInterval(alert(confirm('Session Timeout')),90000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options

1. setInterval(f,ms)

   function f() {
       confirm('Session Timeout')
   }
   setInterval(f, 15 * 60 * 1000);
2. setTimeout(f,ms) + recursion

   function f() {
      confirm('Session Timeout')
      if ( ! stopCondition ) setTimeout(f, 15 * 60 * 1000);
   }
   setTimeout(f, 15 * 60 * 1000);

**Conclusion :**
setInterval is better when you want the behavior to repeat forever
setTimeout is better when you want to stop the behavior later

Answer (score 2):

Use setInterval for this

```
var t  = setInterval("alert('Your sesssion will be expired after 15 min')",900000);
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `setTimeout()`:

```
function handleSessionTimeout() {
    var isOk = confirm("Your session is going to time out");
    if( isOk ) {
      // let the session time out
    } else {
      // don't let it timeout.
      // restart the timer
      setTimeout(handleSessionTimeout, 900000);
    }
}
setTimeout(handleSessionTimeout, 900000);
```

the times (`900000`) are in milliseconds.

Comment: BTW , I think you should use "15 * 60 * 1000" instead of 900000, for sake of readability